# Functions whose absolute values and absolute value of Fourier coefficients agree

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

Let $f,g:[0,2\pi]\to\mathbb{C}$ be two trigonometric polynomials of degree $n$, so that
$$
f(\theta) = \sum_{j=0}^n f_j e^{ij\theta}
$$
and
$$
g(\theta) = \sum_{j=0}^n g_j e^{ij\theta}.
$$

Suppose that $|f(\theta)|=|g(\theta)|$ for all $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$ and that moreover
the coefficients satisfy $|f_j|=|g_j|$ for all $0\leq j\leq n$.

**Is it the case that $f(\theta)=e^{i\varphi} g(\theta)$ for some constant phase $\varphi$?**

I know that when one restricts to infinite Fourier series this is not the case, but I am curious if the situation is different for functions with finite Fourier series.

Comment: The condition $|f_j|=|g_j|$ is unnecessary.
 $(\sum_{j=0}^n f_j e^{ij \theta})(\sum_{j=0}^n \overline{f_j} e^{i(n-j) \theta})=(\sum_{j=0}^n g_j e^{ij \theta})(\sum_{j=0}^n \overline{g_j} e^{i(n-j) \theta})$.

Factorize each side as polynomials in $e^{i\theta}$, express the roots of $\sum_{j=0}^n \overline{f_j} e^{i(n-j) \theta}$ in term of those of $\sum_{j=0}^n f_j e^{ij \theta}$, and see what you get.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  What if $f(\theta) = e^{ik\theta}g(\theta)$?  They have the same absolute value but it is not the case that $f(\theta) = e^{i\varphi} g(\theta)$ for some constant $\varphi$.

Comment: @felipeh If $f(\theta) = e^{ik\theta} g(\theta)$ and $f$ and $g$ have the same degree, we must have $f = g = 0$ or $k = 0$.

Comment: @reuns Note that $|2e^{i\theta}-1|=|2e^{-i\theta}-1|=|2-e^{i\theta}|$ and one clearly doesn't have $(2e^{i\theta}-1)=c(2-e^{i\theta})$ for any constant $c$ so the problem is a bit subtler than that and some extra conditions on the coefficients is needed

Comment: added an edit describing what the relation $|P(z)|=|Q(z)|, |z|=1$ for two polynomials entails, though it's unclear what sort of nontrivial extra relation (eg between coefficients as in the OP) can be added to get $P=cQ$ (the trivial extra being $P,Q$ have no roots inside the unit circle - if they have same degree then we can add only $P,Q$ have no nonzero roots inside the unit circle as the extra hypothesis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result fails for $f(\theta)=1+2e^{i\theta}-e^{2i\theta}, g(\theta)=-1+2e^{i\theta}+e^{2i\theta}$ as clearly $f \ne cg$ for any constant $c$ but $|f(\theta)|=|\bar f(\theta)|=|1+2e^{-i\theta}-e^{-2i\theta}|=|e^{-2i\theta} g(\theta)|$ so $|f(\theta)|=|g(\theta)|$ and the coefficients have same absolute value respectively.

Edit later: Note that one should be able to characterize all pairs of polynomials (of the same degree - though that is kind of immaterial as we can always put a $z^k$) for which $|P(z)|=|Q(z)|, |z|=1$ using the fact that $|1-\bar \alpha e^{i \theta}|=|e^{i\theta}-\alpha|, |\alpha|<1$ and that if $P,Q$ have no roots in the open unit disc (and $|P(z)|=|Q(z)|, |z|=1$ ) then $P=cQ$ for some $|c| =1$ as if one replaces all the unit disc root factors $z-\alpha$ of $P, Q$ respectively by the factors $1-\bar \alpha z$, preserving the degree and the modulus values on the unit circle, one gets eventually to some $P_1=cQ_1$ so the (nonzero) roots of $P,Q$ that are not equal, must occur in pairs $\alpha, 1/\bar \alpha$, one root of $P$ and one root of $Q$ respectively